# How to use c# 6 compiler in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, c#-6.0

Can any one help me how I can use the C#6 compiler in my project?

This is what I already tried:

I have installed the nuget package via this command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Compilers
```

After that I am getting the below error:
"Error  1   The name 'nameOf' does not exist in the current context"

And when I try to change the compiler version in visual studio, C# 6 is not even showing up:

[image]

Comment: Any reason why you can't upgrade to VS 2015?

Comment: Yes, i have worked on silverlight project and it uses some old library and upgrading to VS 2015 ,It will take lots of time and headache And may something break.So i am fearing about that

Comment: I don't understand, you're worried that upgrading to VS 2015 will break something, but you think upgrading to C# 6.0 will cause no issues?

Comment: No, that wasn't me.

Comment: Please post your actual code. There is no `nameOf` operator, the correct keyword is `nameof`. If you posted the exact error message, you have a typo and the error message is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If you want to use C# 6.0 in Visual Studio, you will need to upgrade to VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `nameOf` keyword in C#. If this is the exact error message, you have a typo and should use [nameof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx) instead.

Comment: No, It's not a type error .Its related to the c# version incompatibility. nameof() is in c#6 but i am using c#5.

Comment: @Lalit `nameof` and `nameOf` are two different strings. In your question we see `nameOf` but `nameOf` does not exist, even in C# 6. `nameof` does exist, but that is not what we see in your question.

Comment: The error you posted says that "name**Of**" doesn't exist. That's a typo, or you didn't copy the message correctly. Post the actual code

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

    public static String nameof<T>(Expression<Func<T>> name)
    {
        MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)name.Body;
        return expressionBody.Member.Name;
    }
```

Use this. This is copied from another stackoverflow question

Comment: Please read my questions carefully . I already did it.If you have something new please let me know.

Comment: Sorry. And did you upgrade NuGet?

Comment: If I  have time, I will try this

Comment: @Anonymous have you considered that the error message is correct? There is no `nameOf` keyword in C#

Comment: Let's say string x=null; if (x == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(x));

Comment: @LalitRajput the error you posted mentions `nameOf`, not `nameof`. Post the *actual* code and make sure you copied the *actual* error message

Comment: @LalitRajput, if u downvoted this, I'm deleting my answer